# VBA, Overflow error, For each loop wont take variant

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to change my j variable from `Range` to `Variant` but I get the

> overflow error

If I change to `Integer` or `long` I get a

> compile error.

```
Dim j As Variant
Range("D83:D114").Select
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For Each j In Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        j.Value = .Trim(j.Value)
    Next j
End With
```

How can I make my variable not have the overflow error? Is there a way to reset my memory?

**Edit**.

I made the adjustment recommended, removing selection from code and putting in the range.

Now the `overflow` is on my next for each loop. All these variables are used multiple times and stored as `Range` .

How can I not run into these issues?

```
For Each cellAFS In AFS.Cells
    For Each cellFV In FVOCI.Cells
        If cellFV.Value = cellAFS.Value Then
            cellFV.Offset(0, 6).Value = cellAFS.Offset(0, 3).Value / 1000
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: i think your Intersect of Selection and ActiveSheet.UsedRange is null, there is no data in it

Comment: This range("D83:D114") could refer to a different (wrong) sheet, or the ActiveSheet is empty.

Comment: What did you try to express by using `Intersect`?

Comment: @JohnyL , not sure, do I need it? Trying to trim cells..to get rid of the extra spaces.

Comment: What is the value of cellAFS.Offset(0, 3).Value when it fails? Also, you should ask a new question if a new problem arises after people have given you a solution to the original problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

What about below Sub :

```
Sub ChangeValue()
    Dim j As Range
    For Each j In Range("D83:D114")
        j = Trim(j.Value)
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA `Trim()` function acts differently than Excel built in one

Comment: Then simply use worksheetfunction like `j = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(j.Value)`

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question as now the overflow error is on my next `For Each Loop`

Answer (score 1):

your code works for me

you could avoid selections

```
Sub ChangeValue()
    Dim j As Range
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each j In Intersect(Range("D83:D114"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            j.Value = .Trim(j.Value)
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

And to check for void intersection:

```
Sub ChangeValue()
    Dim rng As Range, j As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Range("D83:D114"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        For Each j In rng
            j.Value = .Trim(j.Value)
        Next j
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: your code worked, but now im getting an overflow later on in my code. Must be a memory issue?